# Is there a way to sort by association property? something like /posts?$shallow=false&$sort[user.email]=1

Tags: node.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize, feathers-hook

I have 2 models **user** and **post** with **one-to-many** relationship. I'm using ***feathers js*** and ***feathers-sequelize***. The response I get when I query post is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Random title",
    "userId": 3,
    "user": {
          "id": 3,
          "email": "user@mail.com"
     },
   }
]
```

I want to sort **posts**  by **user.email** , */posts?$shallow=false&$sort[user.email]=1* throws the following error.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i am facing the same issue